# Is there a way to get a AES key for a wpa2 enterprise network from a login and password for this network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wpa2

I am trying to set up a wireless repeater to repeat a WPA2 Enterprise network. I usually used a login and password for authorization but the repeater is asking for a AES key. Is there any way of getting it from my login and password to this network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repeater will inevitably not have the ability to operate using WPA2 Enterprise encryption and authorisation.

Enterprise authorisation and encryption is usually provided by a RADIUS solution which manages the authentication (username and password), but also each AP will usually have a unique key providing authorisation for it to be able to access the RADIUS server to be able to enable authenticated users to connect their devices.

Enterprise level wireless is highly complex. A typical "repeater" is usually used in the SME/SoHo environment where the need for enterprise-grade solutions are unnecessary and extra expense.

Further research: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24620/what-is-the-role-of-radius-server-and-active-directory-to-increase-the-security

[image]